# Symfony2 DoctrineMongoDB Object not save in database

Tags: mongodb, symfony, oop, object, save

I actually work with Symfony 2.8.0 and DoctrineMongoDB ODM. I have a FOSUser table which has reference to a Client table as follow :

User.php

```
<?php

namespace ACE\UserBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Client", inversedBy="users")
     */
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param ACE\UserBundle\Document\Client $client
     * @return self
     */
    public function setClient(\ACE\UserBundle\Document\Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return ACE\UserBundle\Document\Client $client
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }
}
```

Client.php

```
<?php

namespace ACE\UserBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="User", cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="client")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    private $ref;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return id $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \ACE\UserBundle\Document\User $user
     */
    public function addUser(\ACE\UserBundle\Document\User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \ACE\UserBundle\Document\User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(\ACE\UserBundle\Document\User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $users
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * Set ref
     *
     * @param string $ref
     * @return self
     */
    public function setRef($ref)
    {
        $this->ref = $ref;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ref
     *
     * @return string $ref
     */
    public function getRef()
    {
        return $this->ref;
    }
}
```

But when i want to persist user into Client table, the user is not save in database...

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$client = new Client();
$client->addUser($user);
$client->setRef("1234");

$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$dm->persist($client);
$dm->flush();
```

Any ideas ? I have search in the web but every solutions did not work...

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Did you check in your log that the queries are actually sent to your MongoDB? How did you ensure that the data is not persisted?

Comment: Because the id and the ref are store in database but not the user...
And the symfony profiler send me this : 
db.Client.insert({ "000000003f6049f100007fd3a310400b": { "_id": ObjectId("56819239336f510916958bc4"), "ref": "1234" } });

Comment: You used inverse side in user object, its mean that only clients documents can be referenced in user document, not vice versa! Read 10 times or more http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/bidirectional-references.html#owning-and-inverse-sides

___Remember that the inverse side, the side which specified mappedBy is immutable and any changes to the state of the reference will not be persisted.___

Comment: So I should remove the mappedBy keyword ?

Comment: Change `mappedBy` to `inversedBy` and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you ! It works fine :)